# I want to count a column in mysql and place the results in a textfield

Tags: mysql, javafx, netbeans-8

I have a mysql data base with a column called MemType this column will have whether a member is active. Not all members are active. I want to count the active members and display the result in a textField. I can do the count but don't know how the result comes back. My code folows:

```
@FXML
private void CountActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    String ResultSet = null; // This is to ensure that ResultSet is empty.

    try {
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/club", user, password);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful ");

        // Create statement.
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();      

        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(MemType)\n "
            + "FROM members \n "
            + "WHERE  MemType = 'Active ' ");

        while (myRs.next()) {
            CountRel.setText(myRs.getString("MemType"));
        }
    } catch (Exception  e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the column an alias like this:

```
ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(MemType) as MemType "
        + "FROM members "
        + "WHERE  MemType = 'Active ' ");
```

This should be all the changes you need and you will have only one result (The count of all the **Active** rows)

Answer (score 0):

The result is a table with a single column and a single row. You can retrieve the result using the column index:

```
try {
    try (Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/club", user, password)) {
        System.out.println("Connection Successful ");

        // Create statement.
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();      

        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) "
            + "FROM members "
            + "WHERE MemType = 'Active '");

        if (myRs.next()) {
            CountRel.setText(Integer.toString(myRs.getInt(1)));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("error while counting");
        }

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for taking the time to help me out. I played wit it until I got the following solution:

Comment: Sorry accidentally hit return.

Comment: Don't know why semicolon acts like return. anyway here is what I got for the solution                                                                                                                                                     while (myRs.next()) {
            CountRel.setText(myRs.getString(count"MemType"));